# Disk usage spikes to 100% on windows

Tags: windows, windows-10, hard-drive, ssd

I recently bought a new laptop. Its Acer Nitro 5 with Intel Core i5-11400H @2.70GHz, GeForce GTX 1650, 16GB RAM and 700 GB SSD.

I manually installed windows on it by myself and used Microsoft Activation Scripts with HWID option.

The problem is that for some reason the disk I installed windows on randomly goes to 100% from time to time. When it spikes only those 3 are writing to the disk : System, Registry and taskhostw. It just randomly goes from 0% to 100% in a matter of second and stays like this for about 15 seconds until it drops back to 0% instantly.

I tried running in the cmd SFC /scannow but it didnt find any problems.

I also checked the disks for file system errors but again, no problems. I also dont hear any sounds from the disks when this happens so I don't think its a hardware problem. Can this be a windows problem? What can I do to find what may cause this problem and troubleshoot it?

Comment: Hi and welcome to Superuser. There are several [previous questions on this subject](https://superuser.com/search?q=disk+100%25), did you check those already?

Comment: Yeah I checked some. [This one](https://superuser.com/questions/1042422/windows-10-hard-disk-usage-100-computer-hangs) was the most accurate to my situation. Actually it's literally the same. But I wasnt able to solve it.

Comment: Great, so, did you try the [process explorer as suggested in the answer](https://superuser.com/a/1044240/141595)? What did you find when running that software during the 100% spikes?

Comment: I have screenshots of it but I cant post images still but overall Chrome (19 processes) : About 1.200.000 K Working Set, Discord.exe (6 processes) : About 600.000 K Working Set,  explorer.exe (1 process) : 160.000 K Working Set, procexp64.exe (1 process) : 51.000 K Working Set, Taskmgr.exe (1 process) : 50.000 K Working Set, OneDrive.exe (1 process) : 39.000 K Working Set, Registry (1 process) : 24.000 K Working Set, Memorry Compression (1 process) : 14.000 K Working Set, fontdrvhost.exe : 6000 K Working Set, winlogon (1 process) : 4800  K Working Set, csrss.exe (1 process) : 4000 K Working Se

Comment: I read somewhere that it could be a problem with the internet adapter drivers so Im waiting for it to spike again so I can check that